# How to match household data from two different data sources based on geo and demographic info in r?

Tags: r, geolocation, demographics

I have household data from two different data source. Sample data looks like this:

df1:
| hh_id_1 | geo_location | hh_size | hh_race | hh_income |
| ------- | ------------ | ------- | ------- | --------- |
| 111     | 12345        | 1       | white   | 100k-149k |
| 222     | 12387        | 2       | black   | 75k-99k   |
| 333     | 12356        | 3       | asian   | 100k-149k |
| 444     | 20534        | 4       | hispanic| 50k-74k   |

df2:
| hh_id_2 | geo_location | hh_size | hh_race | hh_income |
| ------- | ------------ | ------- | ------- | --------- |
| aaa     | 12345        | 3       | white   | 100k-149k |
| bbb     | 12387        | 4       | black   | 75k-99k   |
| ccc     | 22309        | 2       | other   | 50k-74k   |
| ddd     | 21687        | 5       | hispanic| 50k-74k   |

df1 and df2 have some common columns as shown above and they have additional different features that are useful for following analysis. I would like to match the households from df1 and df2. Each matched pair should be similar enough to be claimed as the same household. They should be from the same location, similar household size, race, income etc.
I don't know what would be the best matching methodology to use. Any packages available or any methodologies?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after, @ningningning? Do you just want something like a new column that says whether two rows are identical?

Comment: There is a “fuzzy join” package that may help.

Comment: @RKeithL, for each row in df1, I would like to find a best matched row from df2. So I would like to have some matching score to assign matched pairs.

Comment: @ningningning: what you need to do for us, then, is to re-formulate your question to allow a minimally reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. That will allow us to help you much more effectively.